# Is the expression ‘a legitimate rape’ logically appropriate and viable?

Tags: word-choice, politics

Missouri’s Republican candidate for the US Senate, Todd Akin, made a naïve remark on anti-abortion issue  that has now become the target of thundering criticism. *Time Magazine* (August 20<sup>th</sup>, 2012) introduced the Congressman’s disastrous remark as follows:

> Asked about his stance on abortion, the Republican Senate candidate
>   attempted to explain his unqualified opposition to it, even in cases
>   of rape: “From what I understand from a doctor, that’s really rare,”
>   Akin said of pregnancies from rape. “If it’s **a legitimate rape**, the
>   female body has ways to try to shut that whole thing ‘down’.”

I cannot understand the ‘legitimacy’ of the term, *legitimate rape*. OALED defines *rape* as — note carefully — **the *crime*** of forcing someone to have sex with you, especially using violence. Merriam-Webster defines rape as (2) *unlawful sexual activity* carried out forcibly or under threat of injury against the will, usually of a female.

From both definitions, rape is a full-fledged crime. It’s illegitimate and unlawful from beginning to end.  Though Akin spoke of ‘a legitimate rape’, and newspapers keep using this word nonchalantly, isn’t the expression *legitimate rape* logically preposterous and impossible? In other word, can we say "a legitimate crime"?

I understand *legitimate* has another meaning of *real*, and I suspect the Congressman might have used ‘legitimate rape’ to this effect. 
But to me, *legitimate rape* just sounds like saying *legitimate crime* or *lawful robbery*.

So my question is, is *legitimate rape* a proper and reasonable English term, one without risk of causing the equivocal confusion that I felt?

Comment: He meant somebody who wasn't lying that an actual rape had occurred, as opposed to someone who was claiming rape when in fact it was purely consensual.

Comment: Sorry, Yoichi. I have to vote "Not Constructive" on this one. You're probably already aware from press coverage that Akin is about the only anglophone on the planet who would speak of ‘legitimate rape’ (modesty forbids me from saying exactly what I think of Akin - but I can assure you it's not much, and none of it's favourable! :)

Comment: If people want to discuss this odious man's views, they should go to [skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10507/do-rape-victims-have-biological-defenses-that-prevent-pregnancy), where the meaning of his words is a hot question.

Comment: @Fumble finger. I’m not arguing Atkins’s character, or rightness or wrongness of pro-life and women’s rights. I have no interest in political matters in other countries at all because it’s not my problem. My question is simply about the rhetorical problem, i.e. whether the notion of utterly conflicting combination of the words ‘legitimate’ meaning lawful and ‘rape’ meaning crime in one word is viable as a word in English language, which I understand is much logical one than other languages.

Comment: @YoichiOishi-san: Akin was using the word *legitimate* when he actually meant *genuine* or *authentic*.

Comment: Robusto-san. Thanks for your kind advice. That’s why I added a proviso, ‘I understand ‘legitimate’ has meaning of ‘real (or authentic as you say)’ and I suspect Mr. Akin might have used the word to this effect in my question. But to me ‘legitimate’ is felt to be used predominantly in ‘lawful and justifiable’ connotation, which bothered me in understanding the logic of ‘Legitimate Rape.’

Comment: @YoichiOishi-san: Almost certainly Akin thinks many who claim to be rape victims are not in fact genuine. He definitely thinks that the body of a genuine victim would somehow be so traumatised by the attack that conception would not occur. By which reasoning, if the "so-called victim" *were* to be pregnant, he would say that's proof she must have been a willing participant. Akin is bonkers, frankly.

Comment: Cont’d: By the way, I'd like to let you know that I managed to barely clear 10K Rep mark with this question, thanks to your usual help and encouragement in challenging learning of English language. I really appreciate.

Comment: @FumbleFingers While I think Akin needs "10 rolls of rubber wallpaper and a double lobotomy",  I do think this is a legitimate question asking about possible nuances of a word.

Comment: @Wudang: But Robusto's comment above is probably more "correct" than Cerberus's answer below - he *used the wrong words* (he said this himself when trying to wriggle out of the implications of what he said). The possible nuances of words *used incorrectly* by people like Akin are not, imho, going to teach us much about the words themselves (but we do learn something about the speaker! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  - Granted but for many people it will not be absolutely clear that the word was used incorrectly as words change meaning or have special meanings in various contexts, so I think it's still a fair *question*.  Some of the sepcial pleading in the answers is illuminating.

Comment: @Oishi-san: What I meant was that Akin probably doesn't *understand* the difference between *legitimate* and *genuine*: he simply misused the word out of a poor grasp of vocabulary, among other things.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Mr Akin did NOT say that the fact that a woman got pregnant is "proof that she must have been a willingn participant". He specifically said that it was his understanding that pregnancy from rape is "really rare" -- not "non-existant". That part of his comments are even quoted in the original post.

Comment: @Jay: Okay, so by implication it would only be "really rare" (not impossible) for a "genuine" rape victim to become pregnant. Mr Akin still has no intention of allowing that "really rare" victim access to a **legitimate** abortion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Now you're clearly talking politics, which is surely off-topic. But okay: I never heard of Mr Akin before yesterday, so I certainly can't speak for him. But he did say that if a man commits rape, that man should be punished severely. Not his innocent unborn child. For what other crime do we execute the child of the criminal rather than the criminal himself?

Comment: This question seems to be more about the speaker and the situation than about the phrase. If Joe Blow on the street had uttered that phrase, I don't believe we'd be discussing it here.

Comment: @YoichiOishi: Congrats on the well-deserved milestone, and thanks for such exemplary questions on your way there. (P.S. I just changed one of the prepositions near the end of my profile, in response to this good news.)

Comment: @Mark Beadles. To you it may be so. But I who am Japanese don’t care who the speaker is, what his character is, on what situation he spoke. I don’t know Mr. Akin at all. I needn’t to know this person a scrap. I can't be careless of the speaker. All my interest is, I repeat, whether ‘legitimate rape’ can be viable, i.e., can it be justified as a logical English expression, or not, period. No more than that.

Comment: Correction. I forgot to place 'more' before careless in the above comment. It should read 'I cant be more careless of" this person.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Originally, *legitimate* and *legal* meant "pertaining to (the) law, defined in a law / by law". Later, they acquired a secondary, stronger sense of "allowed or approved by law".

The latter meaning has become so strong in *legitimate* that it is the first one we think of, almost suppressing the more basic meaning of "defined by law". This already happened with Latin *legitimus* with the same meaning.

This congressman used *legitimate* in the sense of "as defined by law", which I think has become so marginal for most speakers of modern English that they feel it is almost incorrect, it is jarring, because "allowed by law" is syntactically always possible as well, and the latter is the dominant sense of the word. So he meant rape as defined by law, but what he said sounded more liked rape as allowed by law, which is of course not possible.

As an alternative, you could say he used it meaning "as allowed by reason", as in a case of rape that reasonably deserves the name. This is by all means possible, but it is an unfortunate choice of words here, because the senses involving the actual law are so much present here that what he says becomes a bit confusing.

Comment: I suspect you may be giving Akin more credit than he deserves. I've just watched this half-wit on tv saying that he meant **forcible** rape (which therefore wouldn't even include rape where the woman was unconscious through drink/drugs). Belay that - he's a **quarter-wit**. He went on to say that if a woman is the victim of "forcible rape", her body will somehow naturally prevent conception. So no need to allow abortion in *any* circumstances. I'm just glad I don't have to vote in America!

Comment: @Fumble Now that's pretty disingenuous. I mean, maybe he is basing his statements on his own personal experiences.  That just means he has a cognitive bias, not that he is stupid.

Comment: @KitFox: I know it's your job to give due credit to everyone's views, but how can Akin's *personal* experience be any kind of justification for his views? By that logic, if he'd only ever met one person from Mongolia, and that person happened to be a psychopath, he'd be justified in running on a platform of nuking Mongolia!

Comment: @Fumble I was casting aspersions on his character.  Of all of the women Akin has himself raped, he has only impregnated the ones who were drunk or drugged, but never the ones who fought back.  Personal experience. See what I did there?

Comment: @KitFox: You are indeed a cunning little vixen! I know abortion is still very much a political rather than a personal issue to many Americans, and I definitely get the impression American politicians are more likely to commit rape than their British counterparts - but to me, a man who holds stupid opinions is probably a stupid man. I would not excuse Akin as a hapless victim of cognitive bias; on the basis of 60 seconds I've seen of him on tv, he is both stupid *and* unpleasant.

Comment: @KitFox  OO I like that so much I'm going to steal it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Cerberus gives a plausible, but incorrect, interpretation of Akin's words. Akin has a history of trying to pass legislation that redefines rape into "forcible" and non-forcible varieties, such that only "forcible" rape is really rape in his mind. Akin even later clarified in an interview that he meant to use the word "forcible". Thus the correct interpretation for "legitimate" in this sentence is "genuine"

> If it is genuinely a case of [forcible] rape...

That is, if the slutty woman didn't entice the helpless man and trap him with her sexual powers, and now lies about it claiming he raped her.

So grammatically, the phrase "a legitimate rape" should really be more like "legitimately a rape".

Comment: I don't see how this is different from my answer at all. I just described the way the word *legitimate* came to be used in ways similar to this, and you describe one of the outcomes I mentioned, just with some more background on Akin.

Comment: @Cerberus The difference is that the word history is irrelevant when someone is using the wrong word, and I wouldn't be surprised if Akin is completely unaware of the other meaning of the word.

Comment: I don't see why it should be irrelevant. It is the main thing that's interesting about this, *why* it was used this way. Otherwise a complete answer could just be "he used it incorrectly, period".

Answer (score 2):

We're on a not-so-fine line between "English" and "politics" here, but here's my two cents.

Accorinding to thefreedictionary.com, the word "legitimate" can mean:

> 1. Being in compliance with the law; lawful: a legitimate business.
> 2. Being in accordance with established or accepted patterns and standards: legitimate advertising practices.
> 3. Based on logical reasoning; reasonable: a legitimate solution to the problem.
> 4. Authentic; genuine: a legitimate complaint.
> 5. Born of legally married parents: legitimate issue.
> 6. Of, relating to, or ruling by hereditary right: a legitimate monarch.
> 7. Of or relating to drama of high professional quality that excludes burlesque, vaudeville, and some forms of musical comedy: the legitimate theater.

Obviously Mr Akin did not mean definition #1: rape is a crime and therefore cannot be "lawful". #2 and 3 are also pretty unlikely, and 5, 6, and 7 are clearly irrelevant. That leaves #4: "authentic, genuine". That makes perfect sense in context. He was distinguishing an actual, real rape from a false accusation.

In my humble opinion, the uproar here is all about politics. If Mr Akin had referred to a "legitimate robbery" or a "legitimate insider-trader accusation", as opposed to false charges for, say, purposes of insurance fraud or to harm the target of the accusation, I doubt anyone would be making a big deal about his use of the word "legitimate". Yes, some might think of definition 1 and note an amusing juxtaposition of words, but it would be at most an amusing footnote, not the huge storm that has been made of it.

Comment: Here, #4 itself raises a matter of great sensitivity. Many believe (rightly or wrongly) that rape charges are too often treated as inherently dubious, more likely to be "illegitimate" than "legitimate". Akin's unthinkingly qualifying his topic as "legitimate" rape lends credibility to that opinion. Can you seriously imagine Akin finding it necessary to distinguish his response to "legitimate" murder or robbery? As for the "storm" - apparent insensitivity to such matters speaks directly to a candidate's political competence. . . And really:"**amusing**"?

Comment: "Can you seriously imagine Akin finding it necessary to distinguish his response to "legitimate" murder or robbery?" Well, yes, easily. I can readily imagine someone saying, "In a legitimate robbery, we usually find signs of forced entry, so the absence of such evidence is grounds to suspect that this was a false report made to perpetrate an insurance fraud." Or, "The absence of a body, combined with the fact that the supposed victim's financial problems gave him a motive to disappear, lead to questions of whether this was a legitimate murder."

Comment: My "amusing" reference was to the like response to a candidate talking about a "legitimate robbery", like in my previous post. Do you really suppose that if a politician made comments about "legitimate robbery versus false reports" that we would see this kind of firestorm? I doubt it. People might say, "'legitimate robbery', what an odd choice of words" and that would be the end of it.

Comment: And to beat this topic to death: Regardless of whether accusations of rape are too readily dismissed as false or too readily accepted as true, surely no one would seriously suggest that no one, anywhere, in the history of the world, has ever made a false charge of rape. Given that obvious fact, it is perfectly reasonable to distinguish legitimate [sic!] charges from false charges. To say that because a crime is so sensitive and so terrible, that therefore we dare not even discuss the possibility that a charge may be false, seems to me a serious breach of justice to the accused.

Comment: Jay, turn it around. "Mr. Liberal Candidate, do you oppose enforcing sodomy laws in cases of boy-buggery?" "Why, no; I'm reliably informed that in legitimate buggery the boy generally finds some way of forgetting about it."